# How to add 10% to a cell of a table on MS-Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, percentage

So, I need to increase / decrease by 10% the value of codes 1, 2, 3, 4. But I have no idea about how to it can you guys help me? **I need to use the SQL mode to do it.**

.

**Note: As it's not possible to paste the table here on the post I took a PrintScreen of it.**

.

[image: This is my Table]

Comment: What is consult mode? Have you tried the query design window?

Comment: So have you tried the query design window? You can select an update query, once you have an outline, you can post the SQL back here.

Comment: @Remou So, the exercise says I need to do it using the SQL Mode.

Comment: Switch the query design window to sql view after you have added your table, chosen the query type and outlined the update required.

Comment: @Remou Don't you know how to do using the SQL Mode?

Comment: To expand on what Remou said, click the create tab, click 'query design' Exit out of the window that prompts you to select queries and tables. Then click "SQL View" In the top left or bottom right. There you will update your table, I assume with something like "update myTable SET column1 = (column1 * .9);"

Comment: @Remou @Scotch i I tried the following code and did not work says "error on UPDATE": `UPDATE TABPROD
SET PRECPROD = 1,50 * 1,1
WHERE = CÓDIGO = 1,2,3,4
`

Comment: You can't do a where clause like that. You could say           UPDATE TabProd SET PrecProd = (PrecProd * 1.1) WHERE Codigo IN (1,2,3,4)

Comment: Switch to the design view when you get stuck, SQL view is for when you know what you are doing. Build the query in design view, look at it in SQL view. You cannot say WHERE = CÓDIGO = 1,2,3,4. Using design view as I suggested, you would not have made this mistake.

Comment: @Scotch I was not suggesting starting from SQL view. That is not a good idea for a beginner.

Comment: Never post pictures instead of data. They are no use because people cannot replicate your problem and are likely to ignore your question. I generally vote down questions containing pictures when they should contain data.

Comment: @Scotch `UPDATE TabProd
SET PrecProd = (PrecProd * 1.1)
WHERE Código IN (1,2,3,4)` Worked Perfectly Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only to do not left this question with no answer I'm adding here the correct answer that was posted by [@Scotch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415802/scotch) on his commentary.  And also thank you [@Remou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548/remou) for helping too.

```
UPDATE TabProd
SET PrecProd = (PrecProd * 1.1)
WHERE Código IN (1,2,3,4)
```